connect spring-boot project to sql server express db
I have a working spring-boot application using MySQL via a JDBC driver (taken from a Udemy course). I need to change the backend database to MS SQL Server (Express Edition). I SQL Server installed and functional on my PC, I use it all the time.
I have tried dozens of connection strings, but I always get an error and cannot connect to my DB, even though I can connect to the database with other code (e.g., SSMS, VBA from Excel), so I know the DB is up and running. The connection property I am using is
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;databaseName=dbo.employee_directory;integratedSecurity=true
any many variations on these components. It never works.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Expectations explained in details.

You should post the error alongside the question and a reproducible program to view.

You need to specify the DB port number, also Database name properly.
DB Name usually doesn't contains . (dot).
Below is the syntax of connection String.
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=xxx;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
If you face any error, post the complete error log stack trace.

Thanks for your help. I finally found the problem. the default JDBC driver does not support Windows Authentication, which MSSQL (Express) uses by default. When I enabled SQL Authentication and entered login/password into my spring-bbot code, i was able to make it work.
